# Example text in a text area

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a text area that has some example text that disappears when the user starts typing. I have the code below which kind of works. But...

The default text only appears once I focus and unfocus the textarea, I tried adding an onload option to display this text but it didn't want to work for me.

When I save the page without touching the example text, the text turns to the saved text color instead of staying the default gray.

I don't think I'm too far off here but have spent most of the day going in circles, all help appreciated

```
     <textarea STYLE='background:white; height:80; width:100%;' name="notes"
     onfocus="if (this.value == 'Example of what you need to do here') {
       this.value = '';
       this.style.color = '#D10034';
     }"
     onblur="if (this.value == '') {
       this.value = 'Example of what you need to do here'
       this.style.color = '#919191';
     }"
     style="color:#D10034"; >$notes</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-textarea-placeholder) is provided for hints and example text.

```
<textarea name="nodes" placeholder="Example of what you need to do here"></textarea>
```

There is no need to involve JavaScript.

Comment: I thought of that but the examples I am going to be using will be quite large and multi line, example text in the text area was the preferred option

Comment: If the examples are that complex, are they still going to be useful if they vanish as soon as the user starts entering text? It sounds like they might be better off beside the textarea or at the other end of the link so they are available for reference while it is being filled in.

Comment: True I may explore that option as placeholder is not in ie9 or earlier

Answer (score 0):

The better way to provide hit for input either you can use **placeholder** attribute or you can customize **tooltip**.
You can try follow code :

```
<textarea placeholder="text to be display as example" name="nameoftextarea"></textarea>
```